# Adding label to each column inside a group

Tags: apexcharts

I am creating a group columns bar with ApexChart. I would like to know how to insert a label under each column of a group.[image]

I want under the blue column it show '2021' and under each green column '2022' and not Q.
For this example I am using the code example of Vue-apexchart grouped columns.

Thanks your help